# How can I make 6 images play as a gif with an on click button (Can't find whats missing in my code)

Tags: javascript

So I'm trying to get an 6 images to play (runner0 - runner5) and then go back to the beginning and so far only the first image and second image appears but the rest aren't playing but are in the same folder. I was told to use getElementById(), getElementsByName(), or getElementsByTagName(). But how would i implement those?

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN"
    "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<title>Project 10 11 Sample</title>
<script type="text/javascript">
<!-- HIDE FROM INCOMPATIBLE BROWSERS
var curPennant = 1;
var begin;
pennant1 = new Image();
pennant1.src = "runner0.jpg";
pennant2 = new Image();
pennant2.src = "runner1.jpg";
pennant3 = new Image();
pennant3.src = "runner2.jpg";
pennant4 = new Image();
pennant4.src = "runner3.jpg";
pennant5 = new Image();
pennant5.src = "runner4.jpg";
pennant6 = new Image();
Pennant6.src = "runner5.jpg";



function wave() {
        if (curPennant == 1) {
                document.images[0].src = pennant2.src;
                curPennant = 2;


        }
        else {
                document.images[0].src = pennant1.src;
                curPennant = 1;
        }
}
function startWaving() {
        if (begin)
                clearInterval(begin);
        begin = setInterval("wave()",500);
}
// STOP HIDING FROM INCOMPATIBLE BROWSERS -->
</script>
</head>
<body>
<p>
<img alt="" height="132" src="runner0.jpg" width="107" /></p>
<p><input type="button" value=" Wave"
onclick="startWaving();" /><input type="button" name="stop"
value=" Stop" onclick="clearInterval(begin);" /></p>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Please keep in my i am a total beginner to programming and this website.

Comment: you never use any of your images but the first two.

Comment: if i add "document.images[0].src = "pennant3.src;
curPennant = 3; " would that help?

Comment: you need to put your images into an array, set up a counter, initialize it to `0`, and inside your timer, increment counter modulo the length of the array, and show the image that the counter points to. Does this make sense?

Comment: Can you show me an example? @akonsu I usually get it more by seeing how it looks instead of just reading it. By the way really appreciate the help.

Comment: @markai's answer is basically what I am talking about.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest way would be to use an array and loop through it. First instantiate an array and add all your images to it, which is very easy because you named them with same names and ascending numbers.
So instead of:

```
var curPennant = 1;
pennant1 = new Image();
pennant1.src = "runner0.jpg";
pennant2 = new Image();
pennant2.src = "runner1.jpg";
pennant3 = new Image();
pennant3.src = "runner2.jpg";
pennant4 = new Image();
pennant4.src = "runner3.jpg";
pennant5 = new Image();
pennant5.src = "runner4.jpg";
pennant6 = new Image();
Pennant6.src = "runner5.jpg";
```

say:

```
var current = 0;
var imageArray = [];
for(i = 0; i < 6; i++){
    var img = new Image();
    img.src = "runner"+i+".jpg";
    imageArray.push(img);
}
```

and in your function `wave` use:

```
function wave(){
    document.images[0].src = imageArray[current++%imageArray.length].src;
}
```

If you just need the source names and don't need the Images (pennant1 and so on) for anything else, you could even simplify it more:

```
var current = 0;
var imageArray = [];
for(i = 0; i < 6; i++){
    imageArray.push("runner"+i+".jpg");
}
```

and

```
function wave(){
    document.images[0].src = imageArray[current++%imageArray.length];
}
```

NOTE: You also set the interval with:

```
begin = setInterval(wave, 500);
```

working [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/1ts2bf69/1/) (i just set the file name as content of a paragraph, instead you need to assign it as the source of your image)